# Right shift in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am trying to get a hexadecimal memory address from a text file and shift the 3 most bits and then print the result. 
The memory address is A3BC88A0 and I just want to print A3BC8? However, when I run the code, addr = A3BC88AO but result = 14779114. Can someone help me figure out why this is happening or what to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    myfile = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
    unsigned addr;
    fscanf(f, "%x", &addr);
    printf("%x\n",addr);
    unsigned result = addr >> 3;
    printf("%x\n",result);
    fclose(myfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: three hex digits is 12 bits, not three.

Comment: maybe you want to shift it by 12?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I did that. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not to shift by 3 bits, but by 3 hex digits, each of which is 4 bits.  So do this instead:

```
unsigned result = addr >> 12;
```

Comment: Yup got it, as soon as I saw the comment I realized what I did. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The `>> 3` shifts the value by 3 bits, however you asked for `A3BC88A0` to be shifted by 3 nybbles (half bytes) to result in `A3BC8`

Change the line to:

```
unsigned result = addr >> (3*4);
```

(I put the `3*4` rather than just `12` to highlight that its nybbles you want to shift by).

Note for clarity: A single hex digit is 4 bits, which is half a byte, which is a nybble (not a very common term admittedly)

Comment: I edited this as I messed it up initially, I was thinking it was 3 bytes you needed to move it by, not 3 nybbles (half bytes). The answer by bush got it right first time around, so you should accept their answer :)

Comment: If you make a small edit, I'll be able to remove the downvote.